# Chrome extension API: chrome.experimental.clear.* not working?

Tags: caching, google-chrome

I made a simple extension that contains a button, that when clicked, executes the following code:

```
chrome.experimental.clear.cache('everything', function() {
});
```

but the callback function never seems to get called.  Am I using this API wrong or is it just broken?

Here's a link to the API doc for it:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.clear.html#method-cache

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to include the `experimental` permission in your `manifest.json`. Extensions published to the web store can't use experimental functionality the last time I checked (upload will be rejected?).  That was a few months ago, so it may have changed.

Comment: I do have that set.  This code was actually working a few weeks ago, so I'm not sure if it's broken in Canary, the API has changed but is not documented to say so, or if I accidentally changed something =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API has changed to `chrome.experimental.browsingData`.

I've just landed the documentation updates to go along with the code change: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.browsingData.html

Comment: And now the API is changing again: we're renaming it from `clear` to `browsingData`. Your calls to `chrome.experimental.clear.cache` should change to `chrome.experimental.browsingData.removeCache()`. This gives us some future flexibility in terms of the API's functionality. The method signatures will also likely change in the near future: see http://crbug.com/113194 for details. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mike, is it possible to just remove the cache of a specific site?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most up to date documentation (chrome.browsingData.removeCache):
http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/browsingData.html#method-removeCache